# How do I connect embedded TableView Cell's label to .h?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I made a view controller in storyboard, and dragged in a table view. Next, I dragged a table view cell into the table view. Lastly, I dragged a label into the table view cell. I'm trying to connect the label to the .h file so I can set it's text, but it keeps giving me an error.

How do I connect the label to the .h with all these being imbedded in one another?

I did add the proper delegates: `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

Comment: You have to specify your UITableViewCell class in right zone: indentity inspector, then you will be able to ctrl + drag to assign UILabel with your class properties

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by that. Do I have to make a class for TableViewCell?

Comment: I use to do when I'm using custom cells. Then you  should declare there IBOutlets and cell logic

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object to hold the outlets of your row.

Then set your row in the storyboard:

[image]

And connect them like you usually do. If you need more info you can follow [this tutorial](http://swiftiostutorials.com/watchkit-tutorial/)

Comment: The link for "this tutorial" is the image above.

Answer (score 1):

See this [image](http://s4.postimg.org/nx5mci0hp/xcode_Help.png)[image]

Follow the following steps:

1 - Select storyboard

2 - Select the symbol with two interlocking circles (point 1 in the image) to split it between the screen view and controller

3 - Select the .h file (point 2 in the picture)

4 - Drag the label view from storyboard into the controller

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a class for your TableViewCell and make sure that the cell in IB is using it (let me know if you don't know how to do this). Once you have done that you will be able to control drag from the label in IB to the custom TableViewCell class's .h file.

Comment: I did that, and I imported it to the ViewController's .m. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I tried adding the following lines, but they didn't recognize the label's name: `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AppCell"];` & `cell.nameLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath you would want "UITableViewCell *cell = ..." to actually be "MyCustomCellClass *cell = ..."

(Don't forget to import your custom cell class in your view controller)